# Error while reading floating point values using scanf

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf, format-specifiers

I'm having problem while reading two floating point values for this c code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
long double add(long double a, long double b)
{ return a+b; }

int main()
{
 long double a, b;
 printf("Input two FP values: ");
 //Here scanf isn't reading the 2nd value.
 scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);
 printf("%lf", add(a,b));
 return 0;
}
```

When providing 2 and 4 as input, program is displaying 0.000000 as output.

Comment: You don't check the return value of `scanf`. Also, you don't tell us the actual input you are giving the program. Is it "2<space>4<enter>" or "2<enter>4<enter>" or something else? (Also, if your compiler doesn't give you warnings, learn how to enable them or get a better compiler. If you're ignoring warnings, don't.)

Comment: `scanf("%f %lf %Lf", &floatvar, &doublevar, &longdoublevar)` or even better `if (scanf("%f %lf %Lf", &floatvar, &doublevar, &longdoublevar) != 3) /* error */;` and equivalently: `printf("%f %f %Lf", floatvar, doublevar, longdoublevar);` or `printf("%f %lf %Lf", floatvar, doublevar, longdoublevar);`

Comment: For `long double`, you need to specify the `'L'` conversion for the `"%Lf"` *conversion specifier*.

Comment: what compiler are you using? Note that the mingw.org compiler is bugged in many aspects of long double  (mingw-w64 fixes this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn how to enable warnings in your compiler and don't ignore them.

> a.c:10:11: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2  has type ‘long double *’ [-Wformat=]
>
> a.c:10:15: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 3 has  type ‘long double *’ [-Wformat=]
>
> a.c:11:12: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has
> type ‘long double’ [-Wformat=]

Answer (score 0):

`%lf` is for reading `double` while `%Lf` is used for reading `long double`. So through out your code if you replace `%lf` with `%Lf` then it will work fine.

[demo](http://cpp.sh/3tqbo)